# How to save splunk dashboard as html with javascript/mouseover effects?

Tags: javascript, splunk, splunk-dashboard

I'd like to save splunk dashboard with mouseover effects (it shows the data when I hover over the graph). How can this be done?

[image]

When I save it as HTML using chrome and 2 other chrome extensions (save page we, save page offline), it doesn't have the mouse over effect:
[image]

Note: when inspecting the page, it doesn't show any console errors.